# Getting incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\androidResources (Access is denied) error in android studio. How do I resolve it?

Tags: android-studio

I tried to build my application

but keep getting the error \app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\androidResources (Access is denied) error in android studio. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I delete app/build folder every time I have this error, and it works, but is a bit annoying.